# Kafka Messages are not getting inserted in database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka messages are not getting inserted in to postgresql database. I could see the messages in the consumer, but its not getting inserted into the table. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Sink_connect.properties

```
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
user=postgres
password=xxxxxx
insert.mode=insert
table.name.format=kafka_sink_pg
pk.mode=none
pk.fields=none
auto.create=true
```

Producer

```
kafka-avro-console-producer  --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Kafka_pg  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"kafka_sink_pg","fields":[{"name":"serial_no","type":"int"},{"name":"technology", "type": "string"}, {"name":"platform", "type": "string"}]}'
```

Messages

```
 {"serial_no": 1, "technology": "ETL", "platform": "Informatica"}
 {"serial_no": 2, "technology": "ETL", "platform": "Talend"}
```

Below are the error messages in the log file,

```
[2020-08-12 03:50:09,940] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
[2020-08-12 03:50:09,943] ERROR Failed to create job for ../config/sink-quickstart-Postgres.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:110)
[2020-08-12 03:50:09,952] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:121)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
```

Comment: can you post the logs from the Kafka Connect worker?

Comment: Did you actually run `connect-standalone`?

Comment: Yes i executed connect-standalone

Comment: In connection string you have `jdbc:spostgresql`. Is **spostresql** valid ? I did not see that before

Comment: Its `jdbc:postgresql` typo error in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because of the jdbc drivers where the plugin path could not identify the location.
Resolved the issue by providing the complete path to the plugin in `connect-avro-standalone.properties` file

Initial

```
plugin.path=share/java
```

Changed to

```
plugin.path=/usr/kafka/share/java  #Provided the complete path
```